# C# WriteAllBytes ignores character encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, ascii, system.io.file

I'm using the following code:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THIS IS A TEST"))
```

Which should in theory write a UTF8 file, but I just get an ANSI file. I also tried this just to be especially verbose;

```
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.xml", ASCIIEncoding.Convert(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THIS IS A TEST")))
```

Still the same issue though.

I am testing the outputted files by loading in TextPad which reads the format correctly (I tested with a sample file as I know these things can be a bit weird sometimes)

Comment: If your string only contains ASCII, then ANSI and UTF8 are interchangable. Try adding some accented characters into the string and then see what happens.

Comment: Very unclear what do you mean... Can you please explain what "UTF8 file" means to you?

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes does *not* write a BOM that identifies the file as containing utf8 encoded text.  Consider StreamWriter instead.

Comment: Alexei - I open the outputted file in Textpad, and it tells me what encoding the file is in, and it shows ANSI for the output from writeallbytes.  If I save that file in textpad/notepad as utf-8, then re-load it, it shows as utf-8.  The desired output would be the utf-8 formatted file.

Comment: In case anyone wanders across this, and wants to write a UTF-8 string directly to a file with the BOM intact, you should use the preamble to generate the file header and merge it with your string.

    File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THIS IS A TEST")).ToArray());

Comment: @tonyenkiducx questionable suggestion: if you need to write text - `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp.txt", "test", Encoding.UTF8);` is much easier, if you need to write XML - use XML classes. (it is very unlikely for average person to correctly construct XML with string concatenation/manual writing... and it would be much easier for others to understand code if regular .Net XML classes are used)

Comment: "Textpad…tells me what encoding the file is in". No, a program cannot tell you what character encoding a text file was written with. Only the writer knows and whoever is told what the writer tells. A program can rule out some encodings, make probabilistic measurements and add the author's own preference, including the inexplicably strong preference for saying ANSI when UTF-8 is, by the contents, equally likely.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I specifically mentioned write by bytes, because that is what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WriteAllBytes` isn't *ignoring* the encoding - rather: *you already did* the encoding, when you called `GetBytes`. The entire point of `WriteAllBytes` is that it *writes bytes*. Bytes *don't have* an encoding; rather: encoding is the process of converting from text (`string` here) to bytes (`byte[]` here).

UTF-8 is identical to ASCII for all ASCII characters - i.e. 0-127. All of `"THIS IS A TEST"` is pure ASCII, so the UTF-8 and ASCII for that are identical.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in my entire programming career, I think I've seen someone *actually use* a UTF-8 BOM about *twice*, and at least one of them (possibly both) was an error that was causing a bug because the consuming code didn't expect it :) But yes, you could be write, and there *is* such a thing - `new UTF8Encoding(true).GetPreamble()`

Comment: Perhaps I need to re-word my question..  I need to create a MemoryStream that contains a UTF-8 encoded string, I was using writeallbytes to test the output.  I assumed when encoding to byte and then saving to a memory stream the string would retain it's UTF8 formatting, but it doesn't seem to.  I'll write another question, as this seems like a good one to leave here.

Comment: Also `Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()` gives the BOM sequence. However, `(new UTF8Encoding()).GetPreamble()` gives an empty (length zero) array.

Comment: That makes sense @JeppeStigNielsen.
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THIS IS A TEST")).ToArray());

Comment: @tonyenkiducx I think a key question here is: what bytes did you expect? Because I would expect 14 bytes that happen to be identical to the ASCII.